# Ranorex (adding validation in code module)

Tags: ranorex

Hi i am using Ranorex for my wpf app

In Ranorex recording we are having validation part

but in my testcase,i not added recording file,i am just test case and code module to test an application

please help me how to add validation function in code module as we do in recording or let me know about any alternative

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution

using validate.Attribute we can validate actual and expected data

Answer (score 0):

you can make your own validation function pass the parameters to it and verify for example:

```
public Boolean verifyErrorMessage(string errorMessage)

{

Boolean result= false;

try

{



repo.Gmail.ErrorMessage.InnerText.ToString();
                if(errorMessage.Trim().Equals(errorMessageReceived.Trim()))

   {

result=true;

  }

}
            catch(Exception e)

{

Report.Error(e.Message);

}

return result;

}
```